# Relations and functionss

Tags: functions, relations

I am unsure how to do this, is it possible someone could give me a step by step guide so I can have a good understanding of it.

f(x) and g(x) are defined over the real number set R as follows:
$g(x) = 1-x+x^2$ and $f(x) = ax + b$. if  $g(f(x)) = 16x^2-12x+3.$
determine all the possible values of a and b.

Comment: So if $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g(x)=x^2-x+1$, what is $g(f(x))$?

Comment: That was the question I was given, sorry I can't tell you more

Comment: Sure, but you are expected to solve it. The first step, now set out in the Answer below is to find out what $g(f(x))=g(ax+b)$ is. What do you think?

Comment: I am unsure what it is g(ax +b) to answer it do i have to find x or a and b as im only used to doing these when finding the value of x

Comment: You expand $g(ax+b)$ and collect powers of $x$ together to get it into the form $cx^2+dx+e$. Then you compare with the form given in the question $16x^2-12x+3$. So you set $c=16,d=-12,e=3$ and solve those equations to find all possible values of $a,b$.

Comment: I'm sorry ive just started doing this and its hard for me to understand i appreciate your help very much

Comment: The expression $g(f(x))$ means that every place you see an $x$ in the expression for $g(x)$, you need to replace it with $f(x)$.  Since $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = 1 - x + x^2$, $$g(f(x)) = g(ax + b) = 1 - (ax + b) + (ax + b)^2$$

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the answer but im unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Start by plugging the expression for $f$ into the expression for $g$. That is, simplify the expression $g(ax+b)=1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2$. Then set this equal to $16x^2-12x +3$.

Comment: the part i dont understand is the = 1 part