# Relationss and functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have been given a question based on math I don't know much about. is it possible someone could give me the answer and run me through it so I can have an understand on how to do this, it would be appreciated very much.

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined over the real number set R as follows:
$g(x)=1-x+x^2$ and $f(x) = ax + b$. If $g \circ f(x) = 16x^2-12x+3$,
determine all the possible values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know what $g\circ f$ mean? What happen when you calculate this for the given $f$ and $g$?

Comment: No idea that's all the question gives

Comment: $g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))=g(ax+b)=\cdots$. Work this out and compare with the expression for $g\circ f(x)$ that was given unto you. Then draw conclusions concerning $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772921/relations-and-functionss

Comment: ok ill take a look

Comment: I don't understand much of it

Comment: But how do I determine all the values for a and b

Comment: Bother, cannot close because no accepted answer to earlier question!

Comment: @user338180 Is that answer clear? Or do you need more?

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry for the duplicate I've been stuck on this for a while

Answer (score 0):

We have $16x^2-12x+3=(1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2=a^2x^2+(2ab-a)x+b^2-b+1$. Comparing coefficients we get $a=-4,b=2$ or $a=4,b=-1$.